# Select rows from SQL table based on multiple LIKE

Tags: python, sql

I am connecting to some SQL table through sqlserver within Python environment. I have an SQL table like this one but instead of 6 rows it has thousands of rows with several combinations of deal names and Loan IDs. Loan IDs follow a specific pattern with four digits followed by underscore and then the actual Loan ID.

| deal_name | LOAN_ID |
| --- | --- |
| AAAAAAAAA | 0001_LX3333 |
| AAAAAAAAA | 0001_LX4444 |
| BBBBBBBBB | 0221_LX3333 |
| BBBBBBBBB | 0001_LX4444 |
| CCCCCCCCC | 4401_LX3333 |
| CCCCCCCCC | 0001_LX4444 |

I would like to select rows from this table based on a Python list of loan IDs (~1,000 entries) without the prefix (i.e., LX3333, LX4444, etc) which is not fixed and is being updated every month. If loan IDs were fixed I could use some LIKE statement, but that is not possible as loan IDs are updated and they are thousands. Is there way to provide a list of loan IDs and then look into the SQL table using some kind of LIKE statement?

Comment: please advise your RDBMS, for ex: oracle, sqlserver, postgres.  SQL is very generic. Thanks.

Comment: How long is your Python list of loan IDs ?

Comment: If possible and to be more efficient : you should design your table differently and create 2 columns : loan_prefix, loan_suffix and create an index on this latter

Comment: list of loan IDs could be up ~1,000.

Comment: Given the size of your search pool, it might be worth injecting those raw ids into a temporary table, and doing a join based on a transformation of the composite loan ids in the other table. That would likely give your the fastest performance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. I managed to resolve this issue by doing the following:

I first extracted the loan id from the given table by doing:

RIGHT(unique_id, 8) AS id

I then looked-up to the given list of IDs by doing:

WHERE id IN {tuple(loan_idlist)}